# Facebook Page is frozen

Tags: facebook

Curious if anyone has experienced this. I manage a bunch of pages. One of the pages suddenly stopped being responsive. Here is what I have discovered:

1. The page is working fine for visitors.
2. If I'm logged in, since I'm a manager/contributor, the page will not load at all. It just freezes with a blank screen or the link to it acts dead.
3. If I type the URL for an admin tab in directly, for example `https://www.facebook.com/name_of_page/settings?tab=settings` it will bring to that.
4. I've tried contacting Facebook, but we know how that goes.
5. There is no way to view page insights, update status, or interact in anyway since the page won't load.
6. I've tried multiple different computers, ISPs, added a new admin and had them try and even paid to promote a post.
7. I've also tried clearing all cache and using developer tools to see if I could find anything.

I'm just curious if anyone has experienced this and what (if anything) they were able to do to get access back.